# Read var_export output of JSON response

Tags: php, json, stdclass

I get an API call response that produces this output through `var_export`:

```
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
      'message-count' => '1',
      'messages' =>
      array (
          0 =>
          stdClass::__set_state(array(
              'to' => '23408234',
              'message-id' => '023425F8',
              'status' => '0',
              'remaining-balance' => '152.26940000',
              'message-price' => '0.0530',
              'network' => '7432',
          )),
      ),
  ))
```

How can I access this content?

I tried these to no avail:

- `$response->message-count`
- `$response['message-count']`
- `$response->messages[0]->to`
- etc.

Comment: echo `$response->{"message-count"}`

Comment: You are right, @Rizier123! Thank you! How can I make your comment the answer? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, that your property has same characters in it (dash: `-`), which aren't allowed as [variable name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*

So to still be able to access it, you have to use [complex curly syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

```
$object->{"property-name"}
```